# How can I configure FCKeditor to save HTML symbols as XHTML symbols (`&nbsp;` would be `&#160;`)?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, fckeditor, html-entities

How can I configure FCKeditor to save HTML symbols as XML symbols (`&nbsp;` would be `&#160;`)?

Comment: FCKEditor doesn't have official proper XHTML support I don't think. Unfortunate, but there you have it. At the very least, you are unable to use it in pages that are XHTML (and served as such).

Comment: Can you use a callback to post-process it before submitting with JavaScript?

Comment: I was having a problem feeding HTML entities into a PHP DOMDocument object. After wrestling with that, for a while, I gave up and did a string replace. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was using the old FCKEditor I did a lot of post-processing, IE, regexp changes on the form that I submitted to the Database via PHP.  It makes it easy to replace elements like `<br>`'s etc.  I would imagine your change could be as simple as doing an htmlentities on the field prior to a database insert.

As an aside, I'm using the newest/latest/greatest version of CKEditor now, and it's lightyears above the old FCK that so many people still use.  It's ability to "un-wordify" Microsoft documents on the front end without the need for additional user interaction makes it the best editor out there to me, bar none.  On the new one I've started doing a lot of work inside the javascript of the editor itself to modify how it renders the HTML...but with the newer version this seems a lot easier than it used to.

Good luck.